# Clone/mirror a textbox in a PDF form

Tags: forms, adobe-acrobat

I've got a PDF form in Acrobat X Pro where users can enter their name in a textbox on the first page. I would like the contents of that box to be cloned/mirrored in another box on the second page of the same form:

[image: Sample form]

However, in the Properties dialog of the second textbox, I can't find a way to reference the first one. I do have options to calculate numerical values and perform validation etc. etc., but I can't seem to simply have it display the contents of another textbox. Is this not possible in PDF forms, or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried using the run javascript option?

Comment: @soandos: No, how would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this can be done in the following manner (there is probably a better way, but I don't know it):

1. On the first text box, set an action (right click on the text control) to "Run JavaScript".
2. Choose the trigger "On Blur" (so the script will be run when the user exits the field)
3. Click "Add"
4. In the javascript editor, set the value of the other text boxes.

For example, to copy the contents of the textbox named "Name" into the box named "NameClone":

```
var n1 = this.getField("Name");
var n2 = this.getField("NameClone");
n2.value = n1.value;
```

Make sure all of your other boxes are locked.

**Note:** some documentation can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JSGuide.pdf), you might be interested in page 74.

Comment: Thanks! With this answer and the help of the link you provided, I was able to make this work. I've edited your answer accordingly (but don't have enough rep to make it stick, please review my changes).

Comment: I am pretty sure that you could just have used: `this.getField("NameClone").value = this.getField("Name").value;` but whatever works for you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way!

I accidentally wrote "field name" of the same name from two different text box, after I save and preview defaults and try typing. what happens as you wish